# How can I write a Google Wave rich client?

Tags: .net, winforms, google-wave

I am not sure my question makes any sense.
Google Wave is using HTML 5 and such.
But if I have a desktop (say winforms) application, can I leverage google Wave for collaboration/discussion? Does it even make sense?
If so, what's the API?

Comment: Wave is not an API, it's a protocol.

Comment: I kinda strange you want to use Google Wave but don't know exactly what it is... using just for the heck of using it, is not really a good idea... (but on an sidenote, i do not know it either, what it is exactly :-)

Comment: Where is the protocol documented?

Comment: @LiraNuna It has an API.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can once someone writes a library for .NET that supports the wave protocol.

Wave is really just an extension to XMPP (jabber, google talk, etc.), so it makes sense to have a thick client implementation at some point. Google of course, is pushing it as a web app.

I don't know of any implementations off of the top of my head, but I'm sure that someone somewhere is working on it.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily just need to be .NET (although, I know that was the tag provided by the poster which is why you answered that way).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a sample for this?

Comment: Not true: the wave protocol is only for server-to-server communication.

Comment: Google has release a sample wave client and server written in Java here: http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/source/checkout

Comment: @Jim XMPP also is server to server... any XMPP server is technically capable of talking to any other XMPP server

Comment: @Jim You are correct that it is an extension to the server to server part of XMPP. There are also draft specs for the client to server part underway. This is also XMPP based.

Answer (score 1):

Google has released a [federation protocol](http://www.waveprotocol.org/) that lets your write your own Wave servers and have them talk to Google's.

They also have [embedding APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/) that let you put your HTML content in Wave and put Wave in your HTML content.

Neither of these get you where you want, though, because the way that Google's in-browser Wave client and their Wave servers talk is still proprietary, and that's what you're looking for.

Your answer is "it doesn't even make sense". You'd be better off building your own chat support and then connecting it to Wave later on.

Comment: The HTML parts of the wave client are not part of the protocol, they are just consumers of the protocol. Google has even released a sample console based client.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
There is a Java client: com.google.wave.api:
http://wave-robot-java-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/com/google/wave/api/package-tree.html

Comment: This lib is used for developing Wave robots in Java, not for integrating Wave into Java apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Robot API to write a messenger/relay robot. The robot might record all updates to the Waves to which it is subscribed, and then push the data to your desktop program.  Similarly, the robot could respond to a Wave as a proxy for your Desktop client.  This is not elegant, efficient, or future-proof. It might, however, satisfy your desires.  This robot probably could be hack together in a two days or so, and updated as needed.

Once Google publishes the client/server protocols it will be much easier to write such a client.